# pthread_cond_signal deadlocks

Tags: linux, pthreads, deadlock

What could be the cause if a call to `pthread_cond_signal` deadlocks?

From what I understand ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal)), it is implemented internally with a mutex, but what could cause this internal mutex lock operation to deadlock?

EDIT: I am debugging an application which seem to deadlock on some occasions. A few of the stacktraces look like this:

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0xf6dff6c0 (LWP 32001)):
#0  0xffffe410 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00af15de in __lll_mutex_lock_wait () from /lib/tls/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00aef3eb in pthread_cond_signal@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/tls/libpthread.so.0
#3  0xf4cc8d83 in xxx
```

Comment: Is this a hypothetical, or are you actually seeing this happen?

Comment: I am investigating an actual deadlock situation in a Linux application.

Comment: Don't show just what that thread is doing, but what all threads are doing: `thread apply all backtrace`. You don't get a deadlock from using just one thread.

Comment: I agree with you, this question is not really about the cause for the deadlock as such, I was asking more generally what could cause pthread_cond_signal to block. I don't have access to the debugger right now, but I believe the other thread was doing a pthread_cond_wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one thing to look for might be this caveat from the man page, which sounds particularly applicable:

> The  condition  functions  are  not 
>   async-signal  safe,  and  should  not 
>   be called from a signal handler. In
>   particular, calling
>   `pthread_cond_signal` or
>   `pthread_cond_broadcast` from a signal
>   handler may deadlock the calling
>   thread.

Apart from that, you could also see this if the internal mutex within the `pthread_cond_t` has been overwritten by a stray write beyond the bounds of some other variable.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am starting to suspect corrupted memory. I will check if any pthread* function is used from a signal handler.